Null check operator used on a null value on _formKey & validateEdits
  void validateEdits() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState?.save();
      uploadImagesToStorage();
    }
  }

                MinButtonWidget(
                  text: "Update Profile",
                  color: AppThemeData().secondaryColor,
                  onClicked: () {
                    validateEdits();
                  }, 
                ),

Im trying to fix this error for hours but it keep saying that everytime i change the validateEdits.

Try
if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
  _formKey.currentState?.save();
  uploadImagesToStorage();
}


sorry, it just wont update at all, i tried everything.

could you provide some stacktrace of your error ?
